# Maze generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, backtracking, maze

I tried writing a perfect (only one solution) maze generator in Python using backtracking.

First of all, my maze is represented by an x*y grid

[image]

Where each line represents a wall.
My program will start at the top left cell (labeled 1) and will check any possible moves (2 or 6) then it will randomly choose between these 2 and add the cell label to the stack, we repeat the same process until the stack is full (in this case, 25 items), when we reach a dead end, the program should be able to backtrack by popping items from the stack and to take another path.

For a better explanation, you can refer to this
[website](http://datagenetics.com/blog/november22015/index.html)

So, here is my code:

```
import random

dim_x = 5
dim_y = 5

grid = [[0 for i in range(dim_x)] for j in range(dim_y)]
visited = [1]

def valid(nb):
    if nb >= 1 and nb <= dim_x * dim_y:
        return True
    return False

def list_moves(nb):
    moves = []
    nb = int(nb)
    if valid(nb + dim_y) and visited.count(nb + dim_y) < 1:
        moves.append(nb + dim_y)
    if valid(nb - dim_y) and visited.count(nb - dim_y) < 1:
        moves.append(nb - dim_y)
    if valid(nb + 1) and visited.count(nb + 1) < 1 and nb % dim_x != 0:
        moves.append(nb + 1)
    if valid(nb - 1) and visited.count(nb - 1) < 1 and nb % dim_x != 1:
        moves.append(nb - 1)
    return moves

def gen():
    while len(list_moves(visited[len(visited) - 1])) < 1:
        visited.pop()
    next_visit = random.choice(list_moves(visited[len(visited) - 1]))
    visited.append(next_visit)

while len(visited) != dim_x * dim_y:
    gen()
    print(visited)
```

When trying to create a 5x5 maze, I mainly get stuck at 23 cells, for example, my stack looks like this: 1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 13, 8, 9, 4, 5, 10, 15, 14, 19, 20, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 16, 17

I know that the error is coming from the gen() function.

Comment: Is there an `Error` of you are calling wrong output as Error?

Comment: I am referring to wrong input as error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By popping `visited` while you backtrack, you destroy your path. You should use an index instead to keep track of your backtrack:

```
def gen():
    pos = len(visited) - 1
    while len(list_moves(visited[pos])) < 1:
        pos -= 1
    next_visit = random.choice(list_moves(visited[pos]))
    visited.append(next_visit)
```

With this change, a sample result of `visited` would be:

```
[1, 2, 7, 12, 11, 16, 17, 18, 23, 24, 25, 20, 19, 14, 15, 10, 5, 4, 9, 8, 13, 3, 22, 21, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, shouldn't we pop the unwanted cell?

Comment: No cell is unwanted. You already checked all the valid moves when you visit a cell, so whichever cell is chosen to be the next visited cell, it is a valid one. It's just that when you backtrack, you want to keep what you have already visited, and therefore you should use an index to simply look backwards instead of actually removing what you have visited.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping two variables, one for traversing path and another for visited nodes will solve the issue. Also, nothing should be popped from traversed path as traversal should be the output of this program.

```
def gen():
    pathLen = len(path)
    nextNode = path[pathLen - 1]
    while len(list_moves(nextNode)) < 1:
        pathLen -= 1
        nextNode = path[pathLen-1]
        path.append(nextNode)

    next_visit = random.choice(list_moves(path[len(path) - 1]))
    visited.append(next_visit)
    path.append(next_visit)
```